Prove in place acceptance is $PSPACE$-complete
I want to prove that the language $IN-PLACE-ACCEPTANCE$, abbreviated as $IPA$, is $PSPACE$-complete. The language is defined as $\{<M,x> | M(x) =  1, M\ doesn't\ use\ any\ extra\ space \}$.  Not using any extra space means that $M$ only has a input tape with $x$ in it, and has no extra work tape, no output tape, no any other tape. $M$ cannot write to any cell in the input tape other than modifying cells that contains bits of $x$
My attempt for proving $IPA \in PSPACE$:
To check $M(x)=1$, just run $U(<M>x)$ and see if it accepts, $U$ being the universal Turing Machine. However I'm not sure how I can ensure that no extra space is used in the mean time. I can say something like "check if there's any write to the tape in each step as $U(<M>x)$ runs", but this feels a bit hand wavy and I'm not sure how to more formally do it.
My attempt for proving $IPA$ is $PSPACE$-hard:
I need to somehow reduce $TQBF$ to $IPA$ using some reduction weaker than $PSPACE$. Naturally we can convert Boolean circuits to Turing Machines, but I'm not sure how to convert quantified Boolean formulas into Turing Machines and some input. One vague idea I have is to let $x$ be the concatenation of all possible truth assignments to the original formula, and let $M'$ be the Turing Machine equivalent to the original Boolean formula without quantifiers, and $M$ be the machine that runs all these possible inputs on $M'$ and see if they are all true. I'm not sure how to guarantee that $M$ defined as such won't use any extra space though.

Are you sure your formulation is correct? I would think that you would be allowed to write to the tape, i.e. you have a single read-write tape with some input on it, and you aren't allowed to go to cells outside the input.

@spaceisdarkgreen You are right. I asked my instructor and he said he got the definition wrong. I've updated the question.

For showing it is in PSPACE, direct simulation is the right idea. I'm not sure how formal you need to be. You can just allocate some tape area to simulate the workspace for $M$ and check that you never try to access a cell outside it and reject if you do. The tricky part is detecting when the computation will run forever so you can reject in that case, since it would take a lot of space to record all the configurations for cycle detection. But since you know how many states $M$ has and how many configurations of workspace there can be, there is a computable time bound after which you must be stuck in a loop. So you can clock the algorithm to this bound, which uses much less space. So you just need to argue all that takes space polynomial in $|\langle M,x\rangle|.$
For showing PSPACE-hardness, it's actually much more convenient to show directly rather than going through TBQF. If you have an arbitrary PSPACE language, there is some single-tape TM $U$ and some $c$ such that $U$ uses no more than $c|x|^c$ tape cells to decide input $x$. But imagine that instead of taking $x$ as the input, $U$ took $x$ with a pad of size $c|x|^c.$ If $U$ were able to ignore the pad and treat it like blanks, then it would work in place and in-place acceptance would determine correctly $U$'s decision. But it's not that hard to modify $U$ to some $U'$ that effectively does that, and $x\mapsto (U', (x, 1^{cx^c}))$ is a polynomial time reduction of $L(U)$ to IN-PLACE-ACCEPTANCE.

The number of blank cells to pad after the input depends both on $x$ and $U$. In order to compute this number we need to simulate $U$, and this is polynomial space rather than polynomial time, which makes the whole reduction polynomial space.

@Cs_J Why do you need to compute it?

Even if we fix $U$, $c$ doesn't just depend on the length of $x$ because it's possible that for two inputs $x_1$ and $x_2$ both of length $n$, $U(x_1)$ takes $O(n^2)$ while $U(x_2)$ takes $O(n^3)$

The reduction function must be defined as some Turing Machine. If we hardcode it then it can take infinite states

@Cs_J "Even if we fix $U$"... what do you mean "even"?  Of course $U$ is fixed. "Two inputs"..No, that makes no sense, $U$ is a single polynomial space decider, so its space usage is uniformly bounded by a polynomial in the input size. Yes, the reduction function is some turing machine, and yes you can hard-code $c$ into that machine and, given $x$ as an input, write down $cx^c$ ones. Not sure how that takes infinite states.

The reduction function that you described is (implemented as) a Turing Machine that takes some $$ and some $x$ as input, and outputs $<U,x'>$, where $x'$ is $x$ with $c|x|^c$ blank cells padded. The value of $c$ depends on both $U$ and $x$, so to compute this output you need to compute $c$. There are infinitely many choices for $U$ and $x$, so if you hardcode $c$ for each pair you need infinite state. Thus you have to somehow be able to compute $c$ given $U$ and $x$.

@Cs_J No, you absolutely do not have to compute $c.$ We are showing there is a reduction. Yes, what the reduction is, precisely, depends on $c,$ but we just need to show the reduction exists. We didn't "compute what $U$ was" either. Determining $U$ from the language, and determining $c$ from $U$ are not part of the reduction. They're not even things that need to be doable effectively.
